# Lumen(Laravel) benchmarks are lesser for latest version using homestead

Tags: laravel, benchmarking, lumen, apachebench

I am using Homestead ([link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead)) on my machine and find Laravel microframework Lumen latest version (5.8.*) benchmarks using Apache Benchmarking ([link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html)) `ab -t 10 -c 10 http://APP_URL`. APP_URL is the URL of my three applications:

1. Lumen version 5.1.4
2. Slim version 3
3. Lumen latest version 5.8.2

Benchmarks numbers I got are:

1. Lumen (5.1.4) - **1305** concurrent requests.
2. Slim (v3) -  **714** concurrent requests.
3. Lumen(5.8.*) - **588** concurrent requests.

Please note this numbers may vary on your machine. I have tried on two different machines but relative results are the same.

Question:

Why Lumen latest version is handling the lesser number of concurrent requests than Slim or even Lumen older version? As the history of Laravel always improve towards performance with newer updates, but here the opposite is the case.

Comment: so, what was the question..?

Comment: why lumen latest version has come up with lesser concurrent requests? As per history of Laravel they always move towards better performance but here it is degrading.